# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'. After moving site

Tags: sharepoint-server, deployment, iis, assembly-references

I have a Sharepoint site hosted on iis on server A, now I have to move that to iis of server B. What I have done so far is I have created a new site iis of server B and copied all the content of the site to server B. When I try to run the site from server B I get: `A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.` Even though I have already added the default document of the site.

If I try to navigate to the site with the url of the default document then I get `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies`

Is there something I am missing here? How exactly do you deploy a Sharepoint site on iis? My apologizes if this is a naive question but I have never worked with sharepoint before or deployed a sharepoint site before.

Answer (score 2):

You should be joining your second server to the existing SharePoint farm. Content of the site is stored in the Content database, not the IIS directory. The only thing you should be doing in IIS are configuring the IIS Binding (if applicable) on the new SharePoint server.

[Add web or application servers to farms in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/add-web-or-application-server-to-the-farm)

All SharePoint sites run on all farm members which have the Microsoft Foundation Web Application service in the Running state.

Comment: Our company is about to get rid of the previous server so if there is a SharePoint farm on the previous server then I have to move that to the new server too. Also my apologies but I am not sure what a SharePoint farm is

Comment: I think you'll want to take a step back from what you're attempting to do. All SharePoint site data is stored in content databases and you must have a SharePoint farm to display them, whether that is a single server running SharePoint and SQL Server or separate servers up to high availability/DR. While you're using SharePoint 2007, some of the concepts carry over to more modern versions. I suggest reviewing the overall SharePoint Server docs to get an understanding of the platform - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-server

Comment: You are right, I should take a step back but unfortunately I am on a very tight deadline.

Comment: You will either need to join a new member to the existing farm, reconfigure your A record(s) to point to the new farm member, or you need to build a new farm and move all of the content (and possibly service application) databases over to it. The first option is easier.

Comment: can you please share some sources from where I can get more details about moving a sharepoint site?

Comment: Are you going to add a member server to the existing farm or building a new farm?

Comment: Since our company is going to get rid of the previous server, I think I would have to build a new farm